# Python Pandas plot with repeated elements

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

I have a csv file that contains repeated items. The reason that the items are repeated is that each row is indicating a specific loan that has been paid during time. For example, loan with ID=156 has been paid in 5 payments. So the loan information is repeated in each row except the payment amount and payment date is different. I want to make a bar chart of the paid loans but counting the paid loans by counting the rows that their status is paid is not working as it counts repeated loans. I am wondering how I should fix this problem.

Here is my code :

```
loans[loans["status"]=="paid"] ["location.country"].value_counts().plot(kind="bar", fontsize=7)
```

This code is trying to plot the countries that paid their loans but as I said it is not correct as `loans["status"]=="paid"` could be TRUE for a loan that is repeated in multiple rows, therefore, `loans[loans["status"]=="paid"] ["location.country"].value_counts()` is the wrong count.

Here is an example of how data looks:

```
ID  status paymentAmount   paymentProcessDate     Country
156 paid     $400            2/12/2009            CountryA
156 paid     $123            2/11/2010            CountryA
156 paid     $2000           2/09/2011            CountryA
134 unpaid    Nan            2/05/2013            CountryB
134 unpaid    Nan            2/07/2013            CountryB
```

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: @lanS I updated the question.

Comment: You could group by `ID`, then you can be sure that you only count each loan once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to filter out `ID`s that have already been paid.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(StringIO('''ID  status paymentAmount   paymentProcessDate     Country
156 paid     $400            2/12/2009            CountryA
156 paid     $123            2/11/2010            CountryA
156 paid     $2000           2/09/2011            CountryA
134 unpaid    Nan            2/05/2013            CountryB
134 unpaid    Nan            2/07/2013            CountryB'''), sep=r' +')

paid_ids = df[df.status=='paid'].ID.drop_duplicates()

unpaid = df[~df.ID.isin(paid_ids)]

unpaid.Country.value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

Comment: This does not work. Actually the real format of the data has more than 100 columns so I didn't want to put all of them here for simplicity. I cannot put the names of all columns when I want to read the csv file

Comment: I assume that you already have your data loaded; If you replace `df` with `loans` the last three statements should do what you want.

Comment: The way that I load is it by  pd.read_csv(), so there is no field ID. therefore, paid_ids = df[df.status=='paid'].ID.drop_duplicates() throws gives me error

Comment: I assume it occurs under another name? If so, you can adjust your sample example and I will edit the answer.

Comment: Assume that I use this syntax loans["status"] instead of loans.status. AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ID' 
paid_ids = loans[loans["status"]=='paid'].ID

Comment: The syntax should not matter. Pandas adds column names as attributes provided they are alphanumeric, do not start with a digit and do not clash with an existing method. The problem, as you point out, is that your data does not have an ID column, but your example does.

Comment: loans = pd.read_csv("loans_samp_0.csv", sep = ',', index_col=0)
ID is "id" in the data

Comment: I obviously do not have your file :) As a general rule, you need to provide minimal reproducible example of your issue to stackoverflow. If you have difficulties adjusting the above snippet to work with your data, I suggest opening a new question that addresses that expressly.